# gpedit Remote Desktop Session Host security option missing

Tags: windows-8, security, group-policy

i am trying to configure a secure remote connection to a pc though a guide, and when i tried to find the `Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Security` inside the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) i could not find it. I only have "Connections", "Printer Redirection", "Remote session environment" and "Session time limits".

this is the guidei am following btw.

http://jack-brennan.com/securing-remote-desktop-on-windows-8-and-windows-7/ then its Part 3.

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told us exactly where you're looking, but I'm guessing you're looking in the User Configuration though, as the `Security` branch only exists in the "Computer Configuration" section, not in the "User Configuration" section.

This is because those security settings are system-wide instead of user-specific.

Example picture:

[image]

Note there are two of each subsection (like Administrative Templates), one in each configuration section.

Comment: As mentioned i open the Local Policy Editor run Windows-btn + R, and then open gpedit.msc. Then i when to the path in the hiracy as mentioned in the question, but i dont have a security option. Can't find what you are talking about either :( sry i forgot to post link til guide: http://jack-brennan.com/securing-remote-desktop-on-windows-8-and-windows-7/ then its Part 3

Comment: That tutorial is missing the information you need. Look at your opened GPEdit.msc window. Notice that there's both "Computer Configuration" and "User configuration" sections. "Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host" exists in both sections, but do not contain exactly the same settings. The path as you provided (and as provided in the tutorial) lacks mentioning which section you should be looking in for the branch in question. I've updated my answer with a picture to help show you what I'm talking about. :)